# Is there a portable way to switch text case from the command line?

Tags: text, conversion, posix

Is there a way, portable across POSIX operating systems and locale-aware, to *switch* text case from the command line--that is replacing lower case letters by upper case ones and vice versa.

Using *GNU* sed, I can use that:

```
echo 'Yes, I Know IT!' | sed -E 's/([[:upper:]]*)([[:lower:]]*)/\L\1\U\2/g'
yES, i kNOW it!
```

Which works nicely with accented letters:

```
echo Élève | sed -E 's/([[:upper:]]*)([[:lower:]]*)/\L\1\U\2/g'
éLÈVE
```

But since it uses the `\L` and `\U` GNU extension is not portable.
And `tr`, on the other hand, does not properly handle accented letters on my Linux box:

```
echo 'Élève' | tr '[:lower:][:upper:]' '[:upper:][:lower:]'
ÉLèVE
```

Any solution?

Comment: Does your POSIX requirement exclude perl? (This is a pragmatic question, not a purist one, because I know that PCRE are not included within POSIX.)

Comment: @roaima I though about Perl, but I would have preferred a solution using only the standard utilities:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html

However, if there is no such solution, any "widely available" solution should do the trick...

Answer (score 4):

If you'll accept `perl`, then this solution copied straight from [Perl, using tr function to convert uppercase to lowercase and vice-versa at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5608100/2344631) will work for you:

```
echo 'Hello Élève. It is beautiful!' |
    perl -Mopen=locale -Mutf8 -pe 's/([[:upper:]])|([[:lower:]])/defined $1 ? lc $1 : uc $2/eg'

hELLO éLÈVE. iT IS BEAUTIFUL!
```

I also wondered about using something like `( gsed ... || tr ... )` so that on systems with GNU's `gsed` it would take priority, but on other systems where `tr` was *probably* not GNU that would execute instead. (Non-GNU POSIX `tr` apparently handles multi-byte characters correctly.)